# C UDP sockets, where do packets are stored before to be retrieved by recvfrom?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, storage

I am creating a little application in C using UDP sockets and I am using the following recvfrom function:

```
int recvfrom(int s, void *buf, int len, unsigned int flags struct sockaddr *from, socklen_t *fromlen);
```

I am actually wondering from where the data are retrieved by this function because in my application, I receive different packets and once I'm sure that I received all the packets, I use a loop to retrieve several packets.

It seems to work (maybe I am lucky ;) but I don't really understand where my packets are stored before to be retrieved by the multiple calls to recvfrom in my loop.

Thank you in advance for your help and have a good day !
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are held in the kernel, in some internal buffer. Should that buffer fill (i.e. if your application stops calling `recvfrom`) the kernel will start dropping datagrams.

It's important to realize that both `sendto` and `recvfrom` are just fancy `memcpy`-like calls  - none of them actually "send" or "receive" anything. Sendto copies data to the kernel, and *then* the kernel tries to actually put it into packets and so on. Similarly, by the time you call `recvfrom`, the data has already been received and `recvfrom` only **copies it to your userspace buffer**.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear answer ! I now understand what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

All received packets are stored in kernel queue. It's a fixed length queue. If the application doesn't receive packets ,it will overwrite old one. And update its queue. So whenever you call receivefrom a old packet available is delivered to you.

Comment: Completely incorrect. It isn't a fixed length queue, it is a variable-sized buffer, whose size can be controlled by the application. If the buffer is full, subsequent datagrams are discarded: they do not overwrite. The final sentence contradicts the two before it. -1